# Best way to repair a CAT7 cable

Tags: networking, cat7

I mistakenly cut a [flat CAT7 cable I just purchased](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087FJ7P7G).

Can I just open the strands on the two ends attach them to each other? Like twist them together and put tape over it? Would that affect performance?

Looks like there are eight little wires in there. I know a lot of delicate splicing and then I have to make sure each wire is separately taped.

Or would it be better to forget about the part that was cut off and buy a connector, like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QS681FK)?

I have more than enough cable so losing length I don't mind. If I take this route, do I have to buy a crimp tool too.

I can't believe how much trouble I created for myself by this mistake. I can't just replace the cable because it has already been pulled through an underground PVC pipe.

I rather not to spend more money if just twisting the strands together would do the job. Cable would be hidden away so no chance of later getting pulled and wires untwisting.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the current cable as a draw string for a new length?  (Also next time make sure you have a drawstring in your conduit!)

Comment: I agree with Davidgo, use it as a pull rope to get a new cable installed. Attach a pull string to the beginning of the new cable when you pull it through. Don't twist them together, if you forget about it and put Poe over it you can start a fire.

Comment: I think I'm going to listen to you guys and use the current cable as a pull rope for a new cable. I didn't consider it before because I am worried it somehow gets stuck somewhere. It's a 1" conduit but when I was pulling it through when I was laying the conduit, sometimes it felt like it was going to tear. But it seems pulling through a new cable beats all the work associated with repairing the cable.

Comment: Is there something I could do to make pulling through a new cable easier? Like greasing it?

Comment: It is going to be harder to pull through a new cable with the connector attached if you have places that catch. When I have had to do that, I have just used electrical tape to tape the connector to the pull rope and completely covered the connector to minimize the possibility of it snagging. 

I would consider just getting a crimping tool and some spare connectors it's not rocket science to do and it's a skill you can use next time you have pull cable.

Comment: _"Can I just open the strands on the two ends attach them to each other? Like twist them together and put tape over it?"_ - What are you intending to run over it? 100BASE-TX? 1000BASE-T? 10GBASE-T? Something else entirely? The higher the signal bandwidth, the more stringent the requirements become.

Comment: How much cable is there supposed to be after the cut point?  Where is the cut located (inside a conduit, in a wall, junction box, etc)?  How much extra cable length do you have on the *other* end, or has the other end already been cut to length?

Comment: Also, I doubt that cable qualifies as CAT-7. For starters, the conductors look way _way_ too thin. They look like maybe awg-33 (Ø0.17mm), but I don't think anything finer than awg-24 (Ø0.51mm) can qualify. That's almost 10 times too little cross-section. Also, as far as I know, CAT-7 requires an overall shield, and requires pairs to be twisted around each other. Finally, I have my doubts about the connector. If you expect actual CAT-7 performance, you might be disappointed.

Comment: Ideal brand wire pulling lubricant is available at most hardware stores

Comment: TIL that flat Cat-7 cable exists! Did you have a reason to buy flat cable instead of the normal round cable? (FWIW I agree with the people saying that if you crimp it yourself you will very probably not get the same max bandwidth/quality)

Comment: The higher the bandwidth the cable carries the more picky it is about mechanical things about the cable.  Just the U-turn implied by twisting the ends together is going to play havoc with the signal at that frequency.  Just look at multi-headed USB cables--it's always done with adapters, not with actually having the three different ends live because the signal wouldn't be able to go through the junction in the wires even if commercially designed.

Comment: @marcelm thank you for your responses. I will be sharing the 400 Mbps  internet connection with another building. I got Cat7 thinking I sort of future proof myself but I have since read that just because it says Cat7 doesn't mean it would comply by the standards.

Comment: @Law29 hello, I bought the flat because it advertised as thinner and therefore easier to tuck under things, nail to wall, etc. Total newbie - never occurred to me it would affect performance. But my internet connection is ony 400mbps. That's all I need to go through.

Comment: @bta . It was a 100ft cable and about 70 ft of it was pulled into 1" conduit. There is still 15 ft left over on both ends.  The cut occurred about 3 feet near the connector. I'm still trying to figure out what to do. Try to attach connector to end that was cut or try to pull through a new cable by using the damaged cable as pull rope. The latter scares me. I am worried that somewhere in the middle it gets stuck or torn and then I would be REALLY SCREWED, far more screwed than I am now :-)

Comment: @polaatx - If you have enough reserve cable length, pulling 3' more cable through and adding a connector is the path of least resistance (just make sure it's a connector designed for the flat cable you have, and order a handful of extra connectors to practice with).  Worst-case scenario, you can always to back to the "fish a new cable" option.

Comment: @polaatx consider running two cables instead of just one.  A 305 metre (1000 foot) box of wire would be ample, and you then fit jacks on the ends.   However you need to consider power as well - if the two buildings are on different phases then there can be a differential and you get an AC voltage on your copper ethernet.    A **Fibre** optic run may be a better solution for you here.

Comment: heh. if that's CAT7, I'm Donald Trump

Answer (score 25):

> **Can I just open the strands on the two ends attach them to each other?**

Not if you want Cat7 performance. If you are intending to use this for 10Gbps Ethernet you need to use proper methods for joining and terminating the shielded twisted pairs.

If you are using this only for 12V DC between doorbell and pushbutton, you'll be ok.

> **Or would it be better to forget about the part that was cut off and buy a connector, like this?**

yes and no.

That connector is not suitable for flat-cable, you need a special connector for flat Cat7 cable. To be sure of doing it right you'll need specialized tools too. You probably need to practise on spare cable until you can get it right every time.

You can then use an inline coupler rated for Cat7 (if such things exist)  but you should really also use cable performance testing tools across the whole run to check that the joined cables still meet Cat7 standards.

You could just wing it, but the downside is you might get disappointingly poor performance and years of troubles that are a constant annoyance and faults whose cause is hard to trace.

Comment: This is the best kind of "definitely maybe" answer this kind of question will get. Just "twisting together" is unlikely to make a particularly good or reliable connection and is just going to hurt performance, especially if this is a cable expected to link together two devices with high bandwidth requirements. It *might* work, but when you abandon the job/home/wiring the next person who has to deal with it will be cursing you.

Comment: I did something like this to a Cat-6 cable once. *Do not simply twist the strands together.* Solder them delicately. Keep the soldered parts as short as possible. Do not use tape for insulation, use heat-shrink tubing. Provided you have the skill, the materials are cheap. You probably end up with a 1 GBps connection, but properly soldered, even PoE will be no issue.

Comment: If you have them, there are some nice flat crimp-on connectors (Dolphin is the main brand that sells them but you can buy them [unbranded](https://www.amazon.com/White-B-Connector-Wire-Splices-Voltage/dp/B01L9J4C7W)) that may do the trick better than solder. I love them when I need to splice Cat5 back together. The catch here is they're probably not rated for true Cat7 use

Comment: @Machavity Forgive my ignorance: I would use the White B-Connector Wire Splices you linked to for attaching EACH of the eight little thin wires insider the cable, correct? So in total I would use eight wire splices? You're saying doing this is same as soldering that Hermann prescribes? I am total newbie.

Comment: Correct. If you merely want to reconnect the wires, you strip them, put them in the splice and crimp. You would need one per wire, or 8 total.

Comment: @Machavity and  by "crimp", you merely mean squeeze it hard with a hand tool. No special tool necessary, correct?

Comment: I have done it with a normal pair of pliers

Answer (score 15):

I absolutely don't believe that what you bought would test to Cat7 requirements even when brand new. Cat7 is a proprietary standard, and as such is not terminated normally in RJ45 connectors, but in GG45 - backwards compatible with RJ45 receptacles, but looks more expensive (and is!). And you won't buy the tools to terminate it in a home improvement store. And you won't buy the cable flat. There's not much flat Cat7 cable sold by reputable professional cable vendors, and its uses are specific: multimedia in living spaces without running in the wall. It's not used to be pulled in any sort of conduit. It goes from a jack somewhere, then gets concealed (e.g. under carpet outside of walkable areas), and ends up in something in someone's living room, usually.

You had been had. Sorry to bring such bad news. What you wanted to buy (but didn't know) was Cat8 cable.

There's no splitting Cat7 nor Cat8 cables, pretty much. It's not possible to do in any sort of field conditions while still retaining full Cat7 or Cat8 performance. If done well it could perhaps "work" in that the endpoints were able to negotiate a 10G connection, but it'd be very, very iffy.

I would have had trouble doing even it in a well equipped electronics lab: in addition to a network analyzer (or a comparable instrument), I'd need an expensive test fixture allowing to connect each pair separately to the analyzer ($1k+ just for the fixture). I'd be laser welding the ends of the wire together under a stereo microscope, in a suitable fixture. No soldering anything, and the splice would be staggered, so that one pair each would be spliced every inch or two. That's to minimize crosstalk. Cat7 and Cat8 have quite stringent internal and external (alien) crosstalk specs. I've done it before without any testing other than the network equipment itself, and it worked fine, but it was hard to tell how close I got to the original performance. And it was done just to show that it could be done - beware of bets made over beer. I'd never use it for anything else.

So what you will do if you actually want 10G or 40G performance is as follows: use the old cable to pull a replacement through the same conduit, and forget about the whole Cat7 brouhaha. It's proprietary and you don't need it. And if it's cheap, someone is possibly lying to you.

If you're connecting within the building, then use either Cat8 cables if you truly need 10G-40G performance, or use Cat6e. I have had lots success with Monoprice Entergrade Cat8 patch cables. 50ft white will currently cost you about $50. There are other vendors, but you must inquire on homelab or similar forums about who is reputable. A random Amazon seller - not so much. If they are not in business of actually selling networking cable (and typically other networking gear) - forget about it.

If the underground connection is between buildings, then you're asking for trouble by using copper cable. And the trouble will come when you get a lightning strike close enough. You'll be pulling a replacement cable as well as replacing some gear. Not good.

Thus, for inter-building connections, you'll use your cut cable to pull one or two pairs of half-duplex LC-terminated single mode fiber patch cords (2 or 4 cords in total). Those are relatively cheap to interface with, but you're looking at about $300 worth of fiber and transceivers to get one 40G link up, with an extra two fibers dark as backup or future expansion. I'm assuming you have the network cards that support 40G SFP+ transceivers. If you want to be switching at those speeds - well, that gets expensive...

Comment: I suspect that sellers like this one use "Cat7" as a generic shorthand for "Of course this cable is way better than the lowly Cat6 everyone else uses, because obviously 7 is more than 6, so you totally have to buy this and it'll make your internet super fast!".

Comment: @Reinstate Monica
Hello, I am just connecting to linksys wrt1900ac routers to each other to share 400mbps internet connection wtih adjoining building. So considering that, just attaching a new connector to cut end should suffice, correct? PUlling another cable through is really risky to me. I am worried that somewhere in the middle it gets stuck or torn and then I would be REALLY SCREWED, far more screwed than I am now :-)

Comment: @polaatx Absolutely do not use copper connections between buildings. You need fiber. And it won't get stuck or torn if you do it properly. The fiber patch cord connectors will need to be staggered along your "Cat7" cable so that there's 4-5 inches between each connector along the length. Allow at least 12" from the last connector to the cut end of cable. Wrap everything tightly in thin masking tape - the yellow "delicate surfaces" Frogtape works well.Make sure you keep that tape stretched so it doesn't create a bundle that's too thick.

Comment: If your conduit is not at least 1" in diameter internally, then you've chosen conduit that's too small and you have to redo it anyway. Never, and I do mean never choose "small" for burial conduit. It never ends well. You should never have to fear something getting stuck when the conduit is sized properly. You have goofed and now you know how to do it properly, so you might as well do it properly :)

Comment: To connect fiber to the routers etc. you'll need either 10G or 1G switches. Look for the cheapest brand-name switch that supports either SFP transceivers (1G, cheaper option), or SFP+ (10G, a bit more expensive). At the moment, the cheapest 10G option I know of is CRS305-1G-4S+IN - a Mikrotik 10G router. You'll need one on each end, and you'll need one LC transceiver and one 1GBASE-T trasceiver in each (whether you go 1G or 10G).

Comment: For 1G, MikroTik RB260GS (CSS106-5G-1S) is a good switch. Cheap. The SFP cage gets a 1G LC transceiver, the other one you plug the router to.

Comment: "Cat7 is a proprietary standard" – Could you explain why you are singling out Cat7 here, since it is standardized in the same document as Cat5, Cat6, Cat6a, Cat7a, Cat8.1, and Cat8.2. So, if Cat7 is a proprietary standard, then so are Cat5, Cat6, Cat6a, Cat7a, Cat8.1, and Cat8.2. And secondly, if you consider an ISO standard proprietary, what would you consider *not* proprietary?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I guess it might have something to do with the fact that Cat7 wasn't standardized by TIA for some time, but IIRC that's no longer the case. Also, network gear with the necessary GG45s/TERAs is pretty hard to find, so the whole standard doesn't feel "standard" at all.

Comment: @TooTea: So, because it's "only" a world-wide standard specified by ISO, but not a US standard standardized by TIA, that makes it "proprietary"? That is a strange worldview. Here in Germany, we generally consider ASCII, ANSI, NIST, FIPS, etc. standards "standards" even though they are only valid in the US. And most people would consider ECMAScript standard even though it is only standardized by the *European* Computer Manufacturers Association.

Comment: @TooTea: The reason why GG45 seems not so wide-spread is that by simply halving the cable length you can get the same data rate with Cat6a + RJ45/8P8C, and for longer cable runs, you can get the same or even higher rates with fiber for almost the same price.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Well, Cat7 is different, that's all - and in such cases being different usually means office politics. There was a reason it wasn't done in a TIA process.

Comment: @polaatx I just want to note that since you only need half a Gbit, 1G fiber-to-copper media converters (Google that) will be significantly cheaper than the USD 300 that this answer quotes for a 40G setup. If you have a switch that takes fiber modules use that, ontherwise there are dedicated small boxes.

Comment: "Absolutely do not use copper connections between buildings." Why not?

Comment: Because you likely don’t have spares to replace the endpoints and the cable if a lightning strikes nearby. And sometimes it’ll damage a bit more than just the endpoints.

Answer (score 5):

Re-pulling suggestion:

I suggest you use this cable to pull some strong light cord (e.g. paracord).  The join can be made really solid - knot the paracord **tight** around the cable 25-20 cm (6-8" from the end), and tie off the loose end.  Also knot the cable round the paracord. The end result will be not quite a [fisherman's knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisherman%27s_knot) as the cable is too stiff; a [sheet bend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_bend) would work but leaves the end of the cord sticking out too much.  You can also use use fairly small cable (zip) ties pulled tight.

Wrap over the join with electrical tape, starting at trailing end  and finishing at the leading end so the edges can't snag.  Pull the tape quite tight except for the last 2 turns.

Then use the paracord to pull the new cable (joined in the same way), and another length of paracord so you've got a pull rope for the future.  I used to pull bundles of cables this way in a previous job, up to 3xCAT5 + 4x terminated fibres down a 20--25 mm (3/4--1") conduit.  The longest was 100 m (300') and that wasn't straight.

If it does break, *don't panic*.  You can get a string down a conduit  with access only at the ends, using materials you have or can buy cheaply (vacuum cleaner, kite string, paracord, duct tape).

Comment: I can add more info on the vacuum-pulling we used to do if you need it

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the other answers, the difference between Ethernet grades of cable is **shielding**.

- Cat5e is merely twisted pairs
- Cat6 adds a plastic separator between pairs
- Cat6a depends on the type, but most often comes with foil in the other sheath, or with foil wrapping the twisted pairs
- Cat7 typically adds an extra layer of shielding around the cable (two layers vs 6a's one). It also uses [very different connectors from RJ45](https://superuser.com/questions/1091160/damit-what-connectors-do-i-need-for-cat-7-cable) (as another answer noted)

The wire in your photo has parallel untwisted wires with a simple nylon sheath. It might have foil wrapping around the wires (hard to make out). So it **might** make it more like 6a than 7. Either way, assuming you want to maintain the shielding, I would put a Cat7 keystone on both ends and buy a 1ft or 3ft Cat 7 to go between. Crossing your fingers and trying to put RJ45 in is asking for trouble. A Cat7 keystone is rated to maintain the shielding. Just be aware [you might need special tools to install one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf_5GHT5KO0)

If you don't care about the shielding, just go to your local hardware store and buy some Cat6 ends and do the same thing, but with mere Cat6.

Comment: In addition to shielding, it's also the manufacturing tolerances that are tighter for higher-grade cables in order to ensure the required RF propagation characteristics.

Comment: Sorry, but according to the product description in the Amazon link, that IS shielded twisted pair. You just can't see it in the photo OP provided. You can see it in the Amazon descriptive photos.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your implied question of "is this fixable" then yes it can be bodged together with twisting, wire nuts, scotch locks, solder, etc and will "work"

The problem comes when you expect this link to perform at its rated throughput and maintain a higher link speed.

I've seen these cables work perfectly at 100 Mbit but get repeated transmission errors at gigabit.
[image: Own work - no... my own photo of someone else's shitty work]
 <sup>some electrician used two short pieces of 4 core bell wire to pass through two separate-adjacent holes in a wooden beam</sup>

Point is - even if you did fix your cable, and it works at your current speeds, it could easily fail when new kit is attached to the ends.

**Answer** Replace your broken cable with new ones so there's spares.  Run draw wires too for next time/future upgrades. Consider how it got cut and avoid doing that again.

Since this is buried, its also a potential fire risk if some future user puts POE across the link too.   And its a trap when pulling other cables through in the future.

Comment: Hi there, great advice. What is a POE?

Comment: PoE is Power over Ethernet – methods to carry 12–48V DC over the same Ethernet data cable (similar to "Phantom power" in audio). Often used to power up security cameras and Wi-Fi access points.

Comment: Correct - POE also means there is additional current on the wire.  Not a lot compared to a mains lead, but joints can cause heat as the current levels increase.    To be avoided, specially when some POE links may be up to 60 watts, though ~15 is a more common maximum.

Answer (score -1):

Using the tips I got on Superuser and to avoid pulling through a new cable through conduit, I spliced the damaged Cat7 cable together using White [B-Connector Wire Splices for Low Voltage (100 Pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01L9J4C7W)) suggested by @Machavity. Took about 20 minutes of heavy concentration. I can't be happier. **I am not seeing any reduction in throughput.** I am getting 200 mbps with this repaired cable and a new one.  Of course, there could be drop in transmission speed if I was using this cable for very fast connections. I can't measure that because I don't have the equipment. Thank you so much for the help. Superuser forums have saved my behind many times.[image]