# What is the best way to pull out and replace a damaged UNDERGROUND CAT cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cat7

In order to share internet access between two neighboring buildings, last year I buried about 100 feet of 1-1/4" pvc underground. I snaked through this cable through: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B084L6PHMM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084L6PHMM)
But in middle of the work, I accidently chopped off one end of the cable! Instead of replacing the cable, I  proceeded to repair the cable. [Best way to repair a CAT7 cable](https://superuser.com/questions/1559139/best-way-to-repair-a-cat7-cable) That didn't work well. Even though signal gets through, it interrupts frequently.
Now,  I want to replace the damaged cable. This time I want to get as much advice as I can before f--king things up again.
I figure I attach a cord to one end of the cable. Then start pulling from the other end. Once the cord gets through, attach it to a new CAT cable and pull it through.
Does this sound like a good plan?
What if the cable gets stuck as I am pulling it? Is there something I can do to smooth the process - like using grease or something to reduce chances of cable getting stuck?
There are at least six 90-degree angles!
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you mean 90-degree angle with a short radius? I realise the horse has probably already bolted but 90-degree angle with long radius would mean that the cable wouldn't get stuck.
Also, using a flat cable means it won't travel through conduit as easily as 'round' cat7 cable.

Comment: If you have long radius 90-degree bends, then you can use a method where you tie some string to the cable then tie the other end to a cotton ball. Then insert cotton ball in pipe and use compressed air nozzle to blow the cotton ball all the way to the other end. Then simply pull the cord to bring the cable through.

Comment: @NetServOps  Hello, thanks a lot for the reponse.

Comment: @NetServOps  Hello, thanks a lot for the response. 1. Yes, the elbows are long radius. 2. I recall hearing there is some kind of grease or lubricant to help lubricate the path. Does that apply here. I am thinking too late for that because the cable is already in there. I'm just pulling it out. Or would lubricant help.   3. So use round cable. Something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Maxlin-Cable-Cat6-Ethernet-100/dp/B089QVHNWF    ?  I'm connecting two routers to each other. Is this cable future proof enough or would you go with Cat7 or something else? Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: If money isn't an issue then get the cat7 but cat6 is good enough. The lubricant would help for when you route the new cable. Regarding the cat6 cable on Amazon, I personally wouldn't buy that, because I've never heard of 'Maxlin' brand so I suspect its some random chinese brand and you would be taking a risk on the quality.

Comment: @netservops, Cat-7??? Lol the industry joke cable. The beta-max of ethernet cabling?  Just go with cat-6 or cat-6a. Unless you want beyond 10Gbps at some point, don't waste your money on advanced category cabling.

Comment: Did you try the wireless bridge option from the original question? It sounds like this would have been the easier and more reliable approach at this point...